# Facebook integration in android studio to fetch friends Facebook Id

Tags: android-studio

[sample code to fetch (Facebook friends id) in android studio using Facebook API.please provide some links]

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"_

Answer (score 0):

according to new sdk facebook returns the person's friends who also use the app.

If you want to access a list of non-app-using friends, there are two options:

1. If you want to let your people tag their friends in stories that they publish to Facebook using your App, you can use the /me/taggable_friends API. Use of this endpoint requires review by Facebook and should only be used for the case where you're rendering a list of friends in order to let the user tag them in a post.
2. If your App is a Game AND your Game supports Facebook Canvas, you can use the /me/invitable_friends endpoint in order to render a custom invite dialog, then pass the tokens returned by this API to the standard Requests Dialog.